# Link to official android game samples?

Tags: android

Well, the question is self-explanatory. As I was reading Google Docs provided for Android, they pointed to game samples over and over, but unfortunately there is no proper updated link to game samples. Does anyone know where can I find them? Any help appreciated.

> For a sample application, see the Snake game, in the SDK samples
> folder: /samples/Snake/.

And nothing [here](https://github.com/googlesamples) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this: 
[ANDROID SNAKE SAMPLE SOURCE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/donut-release2/samples/Snake/src/com/example/android/snake?autodive=0/)